# File upload returns incomplete (IE7,8,9) when using mod_rewrite on url with jQuery File Upload

Tags: php, jquery

When uploading a file in internet explorer through jQuery File Upload (using the auto submit code found on the git page) on pages the where the url is rewritten via .htaccess,  the file is uploaded correctly however appears with no link size or delete button until the page is refreshed. It then appears correctly.

I have used the exact same code on a url that does not have a rewrite and it works as expected. This is only happening in Internet Explorer. I am running JFU on a LAMP server.

At a guess I would presume that the JSON response it not returning correctly however my knowledge of JS is very limited and do not know where to look so am hoping some people will be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.SITE.COM$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however no luck